# How to make a clickable label in qgis from an excel sheet?

Tags: qgis, excel, actions

I have location data in excel sheet where each label has corresponding data file for each financial year.
I want it that when i click on a label, years pop up, and when i click on that year, its corresponding file open up.
I prefer to keep my data in excel.
Any suggestions on how to do it?
or any other easier way/solution to process my data is also welcome.

Answer (score 2):

You can open files based on feature attributes using **[Actions](https://docs.qgis.org/2.8/en/docs/training_manual/create_vector_data/actions.html)** under **Layer Properties > Actions**

Comment: but how can i pop up "years" option before opening file.

Comment: create a separate action for each year